# Unable to sort an Array of integers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to sort an array of integers with multiple digits in ascending order.

Here is my Array:

```
keyArray:
(
   978,
   1077,
   1067,
   1076,
   1072,
   1082,
   1079,
   1075,
   1071,
   1081,
   1078,
   1080,
   1074
```

)

Here is my code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"  ascending: YES];

NSArray *sortedArray2 = [keyArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2) {

    if ([str1 integerValue] < [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([str1 integerValue] > [str2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"%@",[keyArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]]);
```

Problem is that this will sort the array like this

```
sortedArray: (

  1067,
  1071,
  1072,
  1074,
  1075,
  1076,
  1077,
  1078,
  1079,
  1080,
  1081,
  1082,
  978
)
```

it will sort four digit numbers first, then three digit numbers.

Comment: What's wrong with the order of sortedArray2? You're logging keyArray ordered by string value, while sortedArray2 should be ordered correctly by integer value...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve what you want really easy, try this:

```
NSArray * sortedArray2 = [keyArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2){
    return [(NSString *)str1 compare:(NSString *)str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger firstNumSort(id str1, id str2, void *context) {
int num1 = [str1 integerValue];
int num2 = [str2 integerValue];

if (num1 < num2)
    return NSOrderedAscending;
else if (num1 > num2)
    return NSOrderedDescending;

return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

// call this when you want to short it...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"787",
                  @"344",
                  @"42334",
                  @"23432",
                  @"3423432",
                  nil];

NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:firstNumSort context:NULL]);
```

[For More Visit this reference...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Hope, this will help you...